# Shader rendering problem in capacitor phaserjs in webgl mode

Tags: webgl, capacitor, phaserjs

I use shader in phaserjs to change the color of characters and also for rain

But the game renders correctly in Google Chrome, but I have a rendering problem in Capacitor, in such a way that the rain is displayed in the form of a ruler.

[image]